# had trouble handling threads in swift

Tags: swift

I am developing a group call application, after I receive ice I have the following problem:

[image]

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40)

Is there any way to solve this?
[image]
[[image]]
[enter image description here][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shq1s.png)

Comment: Please replace all screenshots with actual code. If imgur goes down, your post won't be legible anymore...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that either `participantJoineds` has no element at the first index, or `.remotePeer` is nil.

You should change the line to:

```
if participantJoindeds.first?.remotePeer?.remoteDescription != nil {
```

or even better:

```
if let description = participantJoindeds.first?.remotePeer?.remoteDescription {
```

If the method should end after this statement has been evaluated, you could also do:

```
guard let description = participantJoindeds.first?.remotePeer?.remoteDescription else { 
    participantJoindeds.first?.arrIceCandidate?.append(iceCandidate)
    return
}
```

Comment: Or use `guard`

`guard let description = participantJoindeds.first?.remotePeer?.remoteDescription  else { 
//failure case
return
} 
//success case
print(description)`

Comment: Sure, but I don't know what code the OP has after this statement so a `guard let` might not be suitable.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth hmmm you have a point. Let the Op decide. Serve him as many option as possible to choose from :D

Comment: Absolutely, I added it. I'm also a big fan of `guard let`, but it depends on the situation...

Comment: I edited the article, thank you everyone for helping me